# Adding a custom view controller to a storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios5, xcode4.3

I'm trying to add a custom root view controller (let's call it `MyViewController`) to my storyboard but every time I do so, I get a black screen, no warning, no error, no nothing, just a back screen. The strange thing is, if I log `self.window.rootViewController` the object is of `MyViewController` type. Also, if I use a standard `UIViewController` instead of `MyViewController` everything's fine. Did anybody encountered this strange issue before?

Comment: Try printing your view hierarchy.  Pause in the debugger and run this command: `po [[(id)UIApp keyWindow] recursiveDescription]`

Comment: I have to learn to use po more often! This one's very useful! The problem was very simple, (see @Janardan Yri answer) Thanks anyway for this snippet of code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stock UIViewController subclass that Xcode provides you has loadView overridden. If you're using it with a storyboard, remove the overridden loadView implementation.

I keep getting exactly this same issue and every time it takes me a few seconds of confusion before I remember what's going on...!

Comment: That hit the spot! Thanks a ton mate, you saved me a couple of hours of work:D

Comment: Yeah it's really goofy. It sees that you don't want a nib and concludes that you're doing the drawing yourself. Valid inference before storyboards, but not anymore!